# Why can't I define a ResourceDictionary in XAML and instantiate it by itself?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

Ok, that question was really hard to ask in one line.  Here's the deal.  If I have this XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary
  x:Class="MyAssembly.MiscResources"    
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Purple" />    

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then I have this in some C#:

```
var dict = new MiscResources();
```

`dict` gets created and seems to function normally, but it has 0 elements.  Not that this is some kind of neccessary behavior, but I totally don't understand why it doesn't work.  What piece of this am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are missing the call to Initializecomponent() in your partial Class for ResourceDictionary

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public partial class someClassName: ResourceDictionary
    {
        public someClassName()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); // you need this for the LoadComponent call on the Baml..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I didn't realize that was the important glue to hold all of the pieces together.  I thought it was a little more magical.  Thanks for that, AppleDrink.  I thought nobody was going to come up with an answer for that one.  You're my hero.